# Automatically add parentheses to functions on Tab using coc.nvim autocompletion

Tags: plugin-coc

I just started using [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) with [coc-pyright](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright) on Vim 8.2.5050. In the GitHub readme of the coc.nvim plugin, I found instructions to get autocomplete working with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

While this is working well, I noticed, that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion isn't adding parentheses to autocompleted functions. However, the autocompletion with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does add the function parentheses.

Is there anyway to get this same functionality working with the <kbd>Tab</kbd>autocompletion?

This is what I copied from the coc.nvim GitHub [readme](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim#readme) to my vimrc:

```
" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" NOTE: Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by
" other plugin before putting this into your config.
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
      \ CheckBackspace() ? "\<TAB>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-h>"

function! CheckBackspace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction
```

Comment: I believe [coc pairs](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-pairs) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I already have coc-pairs installed and it automatically closes parentheses just fine if I type them myself. What I want is them to automatically appear after tab-completing a python function call for example.

Comment: Try mapping <kbd>Tab</kbd> to CoC's accept completion function. I am not aware what it specifically is so I will take a look at Coc's documentation and get back to you.

Comment: Update: I have found the function, it is `coc#_select_confirm()`. I have created a mapping with it in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have <kbd>Tab</kbd> trigger completion like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, bind it to `coc#_select_confirm()`(CoC's accept completion function):

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<Tab>"
```

This bind only controls <kbd>Tab</kbd> when the CoC completion menu is open.

Since <kbd>Tab</kbd> is no longer used to quickly go down the completion list, you can use <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> to traverse the completion list. They are the keys that are default for traversing completion lists.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in the way you described it. But what I actually want to achieve is to complete with tab like your mapping does, but also the ability to keep cycling through suggestions with tab. I don't know if this is possible at all.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is not. You could bind the keys that go up and down the completion list(`Ctrl + N` and `Ctrl + P`) to different keys. Binding it to `Alt + J` and `Alt + K` or `Ctrl + J` and `Ctrl + K`(I use this and `Alt + J/K` for a bind I have set to something else) work.

Comment: See the updated answer above. If this solves your problem, perhaps mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get around to test it yet because I'm travelling right now. But I think this pretty much should solve everything. As soon as I got around testing it I will mark the question as solved by your answer

Comment: No worries, stay safe and have fun!